# How to share data with multiple pages in Xamarin. Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make a really basic flashcard app for practice using Xamarin forms. My thought for the layout was to use a navigation stack, where the main content page has two buttons. Button one takes you to a content page where you can enter/add terms and definitions, button two takes you to a page where you can view the terms and definitions you entered.  The part I am struggling with is understanding how to pass the stored information from one page to the other?

In keeping with the MVVM pattern, I was thinking of making a database object, just a class containing a dictionary, and then a view model to link with it. However, I am not sure where these should be instantiated so that both pages can access them, or what the procedure that I need to use is called?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pages are just classes.  You pass data the same way you would with any class - via the constructor, a public property, a public method, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this depending on how you have structured your app.

If the page is already open you can use *MessagingCenter* to send from one ViewModel or Page To the other

**Sender**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

**Receiver**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

If you are creating the Page, you can just pass in the data through the Page Constructor,

**New Page Constructor**

```
public MyPage(string someText)
{
}
```

**Sender**

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPage(<YourTextHere>)));
```

**or via a Property**

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPage() { SomneProperty = "blach" ));
```

Comment: What about sending from the child page to the parent page?